# How to write this SQL Query with a list of numbers in the WHERE filter

Tags: sql-server, filter, numbers, where-clause

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

My SQL query stands as below:

```
USE Mydatabase
SELECT TravelagencyId, Name
FROM dbo.TravelAgency
```

I need to add this WHERE line to the query:

```
WHERE TravelagencyId = (650,651,652,800,952,976)
```

I am aware that if the list of numbers are consecutive or fall between a range, I can write something like:

```
WHERE TravelagencyId BETWEEN 650 AND 976
```

but here there are Ids that I want to exclude from the filter.

Any help on how to write this `WHERE` filter?

Comment: Use WHERE TravelagencyId NOT IN (650,651,652,800,952,976)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using not in where you want to exclude the values that you have.

```
USE Mydatabase
SELECT TravelagencyId, Name
FROM dbo.TravelAgency
where TravelagencyId in (650,651,652,800,952,976)
```

Comment: Perhaps I confused you. In fact, the numbers in the bracket are those I need to extract!

Comment: try with in then. I have modified the answer.